# Windows Binary working on CMD but not (always) with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, windows, visual-c++, cmd, processbuilder

I developed a `C++` application and I want to call it from my `Java` application. For this I'm using `ProcessBuilder`:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
String processOutput = readFromProcess(process);

val exitCode = process.waitFor();
if (exitCode != 0)
{
    // Exception
}

return processOutput;
```

Here is how I read the process' output:

```
public static String readFromProcess(Process process) throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    String lineSeparator = lineSeparator();
    try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream())))
    {
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append(lineSeparator);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
}
```

I'm getting:

```
exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

This seems to mean `The application was unable to start correctly` and I do not even get the initial copyright console print at the beginning of the `EXE`'s code.

If I run the `EXE` on `CMD` instead it will run successfully even though I passed exactly the same arguments. Why does this happen? I compiled the code for `Linux` and `Mac OS X` but both of them run fine on their respective operating systems via `Java` and the `Terminal`. The mentioned exit code `0xC0000005` only occurs on `Windows` and not just on my PC. 2 other users observed this issue as well. Sometimes the `Windows` `EXE` would still run from `Java` though which is even more odd.

The `C++` compilation flags I use are:

```
# /MD Causes the application to use the multithread-specific and DLL-specific version of the run-time library:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/2kzt1wy3(v=vs.140)
# /Ox (Full Optimization): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/59a3b321(v=vs.140)
# /GL (Whole Program Optimization): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/0zza0de8(v=vs.140)
# /cgthreads (Code Generation Threads): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn631956(v=vs.140)
# /MP (Build with Multiple Processes): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/bb385193(v=vs.140)
# /fp (Specify Floating-Point Behavior): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/e7s85ffb(v=vs.140)
# /Gw (Optimize Global Data): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dn305952(v=vs.140)
# /GS (Buffer Security Check): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/8dbf701c(v=vs.140)
# /favor (Optimize for Architecture Specifics): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms173505(v=vs.140)
# /Qpar (Auto-Parallelizer): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh923900(v=vs.140)
# /EH (Exception Handling Model): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/1deeycx5(v=vs.140)
# DNDEBUG: Disable assert macro evaluation
set(OPTIMIZATIONS "/MD /Ox /GL /cgthreads8 /MP8 /fp:fast /Gw /GS- /favor:INTEL64 /Qpar /EHs /EHc- /DNDEBUG")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${OPTIMIZATIONS}")
```

Comment: **NT Status** 0xC0000005 (-1073741819)

**Windows Error** 0x3E6 (998)



**NT Status Message**:

The instruction at 0x%p referenced memory at 0x%p. The memory could not be %s.





**Windows Error Message**:

Invalid access to memory location.

Comment: There is a bug in your program. You are using memory that has been freed (ie by an object/string/value going out of scope) or something is null (and shouldn't be) and you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the passed arguments weren't the same because `Java` interprets an empty string as no argument on `Windows`. Therefore, it indexed the array of arguments out of bounds and still refused to print anything from before the memory error even happened which is non-intuitive.